# yii регистрация

Tags: php

Есть ли механизм для подтверждения номера телефона при регистации путям смс с кодом,который потом нужно вести (для украинских операторов)?Спасибо.

Answer (score 1):

Насколько мне известно, штатного механизма для подтверждения телефона и работы с SMS в Yii фреймворке нет. В тоже время есть расширения, которые добавляют соответствующий функционал.

Например, [расширение для работы с SMS для Yii2](http://www.yiiframework.com/extension/yii2-sms). Если используете версию из семейства 1.X, то для неё также можно поискать подобные расширения.

Если же ни одно из готовых расширений Вас не устроит, придётся придётся писать своё собственное. Как-то так...

Comment: а стороннего плагина.Для вордпреса есть что то подобное.Я думал и здесь может найдется.

Comment: @RomaTulaydan,расширения это своего рода аналог плагинов. Только нужно понимать, что фреймворк не является готовым решением, в отличие от CMS (того же WordPress). Поэтому, даже если Вам удастся подобрать готовое расширение, оно лишь обеспечит базовый функционал для программирования.  Реализацию готового рабочего механизма Вам в любом случае придётся выполнить уже самостоятельно.

Comment: это само собой)Спасибо.Думал что кто то уже имел подобный опыт

Comment: На подобных сайтах люди как раз и обмениваются опытом. Подсказывают, направляют, помогают встать на ноги...Другое дело, чего Вы сами на самом деле хотите от сообщества... Ничего личного.